# Working with many to many database in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm working with many to many databases in Django but I do not understand one piece of code.

what's the meaning of 5 in the below line of code:

`areadata.objects.get(id = area_id).pub.add(mymodel.objects.get(id = restaurant_id),5)`

If anyone knows that's meaning please explain it to me.

Comment: from the official doc, the [**`add(...)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) method doesn't accept such values

Comment: it works i use it in my project

Comment: I want to know whats that meaning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It refers to the `id` of a row in the `mymodel` table.

- `areadata.objects.get(id=area_id).pub.add(mymodel.objects.get(id=restaurant_id), 5)` calls
- `create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager.`
  `def add(self, *objs, through_defaults=None)`
  (with `objs = (<mymodel: mymodel object (restaurant_id)>, 5)`), which calls
- `create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager.`
  `def _add_items(self, source_field_name, target_field_name, *objs, through_defaults=None)`, which calls
- `create_forward_many_to_many_manager.<locals>.ManyRelatedManager.`
  `def _get_target_ids(self, target_field_name, objs)`

Truncated for brevity:

```py
def _get_target_ids(self, target_field_name, objs):
    ...
    for obj in objs:
        if isinstance(obj, self.model):
            ...
            target_id = target_field.get_foreign_related_value(obj)[0]
            ...
            target_ids.add(target_id)
        elif isinstance(obj, Model):
            raise TypeError(...)
        else:
            target_ids.add(obj)
    return target_ids
```

Since `5` is neither an instance of `mymodel` nor `Model`, it is considered as an `id` of `mymodel`.

The resulting `target_ids` is `{restaurant_id, 5}`.